# Adding new columns to a table in Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a CSV file in blob storage with the following format:

```
**Column,DataType**
Acc_ID, int
firstname, nvarchar(500)
lastname, nvarchar(500)
```

I am trying to read this file in data factory and loop through the column names and check the destination table if these columns already exits, if not I want to create the missing columns in the SQL table.

I know that we can use the following SQL query to create columns that do not exist.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'contact_info' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'acc_id')
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE contact_info
    ADD acc_id int NULL
END;
```

But I am not sure if we can read the CSV file and pass the column names from the CSV file to the above SQL query in a data factory pipeline. Any suggestions for this please?

Comment: Is [additional column during copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#add-additional-columns-during-copy) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a column if not exist using the Pre-copy script in the `Copy data` activity.

•   Table columns **before executing the pipeline**.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'contact_info'
```

[image]

•   **Source file:**

[image]

**ADF pipeline:**

1. Using the `lookup` activity, get the list columns and datatypes by connecting the source dataset to the source file.

[image]

**Output of lookup activity**:

[image]

2. Connect the `lookup` output to the `ForEach` activity to loop all the values from the lookup.

`@activity('Lookup1').output.value`

[image]

3. Add `Copy data` activity inside `ForEach` activity and connect the **source** to the SQL table. Select **query** instead of a table in Use query properties. Write a query that does not result in any result as we are using this copy activity only to add a column to the table if not exist.

`select * from dbo.contact_info where 1= 2`

[image]

4. In the `Copy data` activity **sink**, connect the sink dataset to the SQL table, and in the **Pre-copy script** write your query to add a new column. Here use the current `ForEach` loop items (column, datatype) values instead of hardcoding the values as below.

   ```
   @{concat('IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ','''','contact_info','''',' AND COLUMN_NAME = ','''',item().Column,'''',') ALTER TABLE contact_info ADD ',item().Column,' ', item().DataType,' NULL')}
   ```

[image]

5. When the pipeline is executed, the FoEach loop executes till it completes all the values in the lookup output and creates a new column in the table if not exist.

Columns in the table **after the pipeline is executed**:

[image]

Comment: This was very helpful! Works well!